# Nodemailer error: [Error: No transport method defined]

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer with sendgrid and i am getting the error : `[Error: No transport method defined]`

I am setting up the transport like so:

```
var email = nodemailer.createTransport("STMP", {
service: "Sendgrid",
auth: {
    user: "username",
    pass: "pass"
}
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it says "STMP" rather than "SMTP" - simple typo

Answer (score 0):

You're using a wrong method... Instead of STMP use SMPT(simple mail transfer protocol).
As Below

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'youremail@address.com',
        pass: 'yourpassword'
    }
})
```

Answer (score -2):

There was just the typing mistake. You wrote the wrong spelling of SMTP.
So, the correct solution was :-

```
var email = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    service: "Sendgrid",
    auth: {
        user: "username",
        pass: "pass"
    }
})
```

Comment: Actually correcting mentioned wrong spelling in your own answer might have helped here.